# jQuery Xml parsing what is the problem here?

Tags: jquery

I have this code where i's like to traverse through all `com.abc.db.ConfigInfo` row, and if any of them contains `cfgId` as `141` alert(cfgName)

**Updated**

```
alert(xml);
                        $(xml).find('list com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo').each(function()
                        {
                            alert("enter the dragon");
                            if($(this).find('cfgId').text()=="141")  
                            alert($(this).find('cfgName').text()); 
                        });
```

My XML

```
<list>
<com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<cfgId>83</cfgId>
<cfgName>test</cfgName>
</com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
<cfgId>102</cfgId>
<cfgName>cfgname1</cfgName>
</com.abc.db.ConfigInfo>
    </list>
```

Comment: so what's the problem in that?

Comment: @Vivek: it is not getting inside the `each` loop itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correctly to me. But in your xml example you don't have any `cfgId` as `141`. And this is a good reason why you don't get any alert...

Comment: @Ovidio l.: At least it should enter my loop, see my updated question part

Comment: What's with the `xml` variable? Do you use [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)?

Comment: l.: I get it from server side response var xml=client.responseText;

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), where you can specify `dataType: "xml"`. So you will need to do something like `xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);` and then use `xmlDoc` to traverse the document.

Answer (score 0):

start traversing from root node..

```
newXml = $.parseXML(xml)// parse your xml
$(newXml).find('list com.abc.db.ConfigInfo').each(function(){                            
if($(this).find('cfgId').text()=="141")                             
alert($(this).find('cfgName').text());                        
 });
```

Comment: Vivek: no js error, i am trying in IE(it shows an icon bottom left, if there is any js error)

Comment: use `newXml = $.parseXML(xml)` and then use this newXml to traverse

Answer (score 0):

Sizzle (the library jQuery uses for `.find` and its friends) will interpret your `"com.abc.db.ConfigInfo"` as "node `com` with classes `abc`, `db` and `ConfigInfo`".

You can try if escaping the dots works (`"list com\\.abc\\.db\\.ConfigInfo"`, double backslash because these are JS strings and you need to escape the backslash) but if possible I suggest you pick tag names without dots. Underscores should work better.

Comment: I used your way but i can only get alert(xml);

Comment: You need to also get rid of the `list` bit, as jQuery takes that as the root element (as @Vivek said). Then it works for me, see: http://jsfiddle.net/yMQSZ/